# In selenium/appium is there a way to check/verify whether the click action is successful or unsuccessful after clicking on a button etc

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I would like to know whether the click action can be verified after clicking on a WebElements. In selenium/Appium, text can be verified likewise is there any way to verify whether the click action can be verified after clicking on the web elements

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a try/catch block, and return true if the click was successful.
Also, the appium server has a record about click in format:

[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /element/ec6d74a7-202b-4b67-9da8-64588d206e38/click] to [POST http://localhost:8201/wd/hub/session/19eb6a10-fb21-4fd4-a9e5-096313bf43ce/element/ec6d74a7-202b-4b67-9da8-64588d206e38/click] with body: {“element”:“ec6d74a7-202b-4b67-9da8-64588d206e38”}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {“sessionId”:“19eb6a10-fb21-4fd4-a9e5-096313bf43ce”,“status”:0,“value”:true}

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is the verification possible using javascript executor?